# break в цикле for

Tags: python, selenium

Как после десятого цикла поставить break?

```
for item in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '// *[ @ id = "div2"] / div / div[2] / a[1]'):
    time.sleep(4)
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", item)
```

Comment: Примерно так: ```i+=1; if i>10 break;```

Comment: @Владимир Клыков Можно было сделать и так:  for i in range(10):

Comment: `for i, item in enumerate(driver.find_elements(...)):`, `if i>10: break`

Comment: Можно сделать то же срезом: `for item in driver.find_elements(...)[:10]:`.